# Heat of Sublimation of GaAs and SiC

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, elements

I am trying to find values for the heat of sublimation of GaAs and SiC, but can't find anything. I also tried searching for the heat of fusion and vaporization, to calculate the heat of sublimation from them, but I also can't find anything here for these materials. Does anyone know a good source? Or is it called differently for compounds?

Comment: Maybe the people at chemistry.se could be of more help.

Comment: Thermo was never my strong suit, so I won't post an answer. But SiC doesn't even melt, as it decomposes first. And when it sublimates, you get several different species. What you might want instead is the heat of formation, of maybe Si(g) + C(s) -> SiC(s) ?

Comment: Thank you, @HiddenBabel, that might be the reason. I pretty much want to know the energy needed to remove a surface atom from solid material (assumed to be the heat of sublimation for other materilas), so I'm not sure  if the heat of formation will work.

Comment: @J.G. I will ask there too, thanks.